# Python, dataframes: How to make dictionary/series/dataframe for each value whose key is duplicate in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes created like this:

```
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
| VideoID |   long | lat | viewerCount |
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
| 123     |   -1.1 | 1.1 |     25      |
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
| 123     |   -1.1 | 1.1 |     20      |
+---------+--------+-----+-------------+
```

The `videoIDs` are the `IDs` for video live streaming on facebook. And `viewerCount` is the number of viewers watching them.
I add the values refreshing after every 30 seconds. The `videoIDs` mostly will be duplicates but the `viewerCount` can will change. 
So what I am trying is to store the new `viewerCount` also but no duplication of videoIDs 
(i.e.: the viewerCount is now not a single columns but can be a dictionary or series). Something like this:
[image: the table showing the format i expect (to clear the point)]

Comment: Do you want it in this format in order for it to be presentable? or do you want to do further processing/analysis on it after?

Comment: @O.Suleiman I want it for further analysis. I'm making a database. The code will run for a month

Comment: Well, what you have here is what is called "Unnormalized Form" (UNF) which is not ideal for storing data in a database. What I suggest is that you can build a normalized model by having two tables instead of one: one table (main table) which contains the static data (the data that doesn't change) about the videos and, of course, has the video ids, and the other one is the counter table which has a new record each time you get a new count. After having this model, you can analyze your data using JOINs, GROUP BYs, ... etc. similar to the way you would analyze any transactional data.

Comment: This can help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @O.Suleiman I understand your logic. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe DataFrame.groupby() can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have a comment before I answer your question. Unless you are dealing with "big-data" *(where the in-memory join operation outcosts the storage space and possible update costs)* it is advisable that you split your table into two.
- The first will contain the Videos details `Video_id*, longitude, latitude, location`
- The second table will contain the `Video_id, refreshes and Views`

.

With that being said, there are several options to reach this final representation. The solution that I would use my self, would be storing the `Viewers_count` as a **list**. Lists would be beneficial, since one would remove the `Num_refresh` all together, because it can be recalculated from the elements index. 
Using dicts will be needlessly expensive and complex in this case, but I will add the syntax as well.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': list("aabb"), 
                   'location': list("xxyy"),
                   'views': [3, 4, 1, 2]})
#   id location  views
# 0  a        x      3
# 1  a        x      4
# 2  b        y      1
# 3  b        y      2

grouped_df = (df
              .groupby(["id", "location"])["views"] # Create a group for each [id, location] and select view
              .apply(np.hstack)                     # Transform the grouped views to a list
            # .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(range(len(x)), x))) # Dict
              .reset_index())                       # Move id and location to regular columns

#   id location   views
# 0  a        x  [3, 4]
# 1  b        y  [1, 2]
```

---

Update:

You've mentioned in the comments the problem of nested lists during the iterations. You could replace `list` by `np.hstack`.

```
# Second iterations 
iter_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': list("aabb"), 
                       'location': list("xxyy"),
                       'views': [30, 40, 10, 20]})

grouped_df = (grouped_df
              .append(iter_2)                       # Add the rows of the new dataframe to the grouped_df
              .groupby(["id", "location"])["views"]
              .apply(np.hstack)
              .reset_index())

#   id location           views
# 0  a        x  [3, 4, 30, 40]
# 1  b        y  [1, 2, 10, 20]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make a dictionary with number of refreshes and viewerCount in each row. Just replace list with dictionary.

Comment: The problem is as the loop itereates the new values are grouped for duplicates but they are added in nested list. They should be only in One-D list.

Comment: @ShaikhBatmann I've updated the answer to include the dicts and solve the nested lists problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its solved exactly what I want. You are a life savior.